# Cancel function execution with SweetAlert

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, frontend, sweetalert2

I have buttons to execute scripts in my Sheets Addon

```
<button class="button-68" role="button" onclick="morphf3994()">Unir columnas con el mismo encabezado</button>

<script>
function morphf3994() {
  swaload()
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(swalsuccess)
  .withFailureHandler(swalerror)
  .merge_Columns();
}
</script>
```

And SweetAlert shows a Executing... alert while the script is making its function.

```
<script>
function swaload() {

      Swal.fire({
      titleText: "Ejecutando...",
      text: 'Por favor, no toques ni cierres el documento.',
      icon: 'warning',
      allowOutsideClick: false,
      preConfirm: Swal.showLoading(),
      showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
      showConfirmButton: false,
      showCancelButton: true,
    })
}
</script>
```

The Alert has just a Cancel button, but I don't know how to implement the CancelButton to stop the button function before finishing (in this case the .merge_Columns() function. Right now the Cancel Button just close the loading window.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use then function of swal in your code. [Reference](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples)

```
<script>
    function swaload() {
          Swal.fire({
          titleText: "Ejecutando...",
          text: 'Por favor, no toques ni cierres el documento.',
          icon: 'warning',
          allowOutsideClick: false,
          preConfirm: Swal.showLoading(),
          showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
          showConfirmButton: false,
          showCancelButton: true,
        }).then((result) => {
          if (result.isConfirmed) {
            return true;
          } else if (result.isDenied) {
            return false;
          }
        })
    }
</script>
```

apply condition in morphf3994 function

```
<script>
    function morphf3994() {
      if(swaload()){
          google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(swalsuccess)
          .withFailureHandler(swalerror)
          .merge_Columns();
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: With this code the script is not executing. It shows the loading screen but not apply the function .merge_Columns().

Answer (score 0):

Well, with this edit the function is running, but what i need is the code to STOP the .merge_Columns from executing. The function is already running when the Cancel button appears but I don't know the apps script code to stop the function.

```
 <script>
    function morphf9566() {
      if(swaload()){
      }
      else {
          google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(swalsuccess2)
          .withFailureHandler(swalerror)
          .merge_Columns();
      }
    }
</script>
```

Thanks